# Help needed for Simple derivation for duality of matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, mass, wave-particle-duality

A teacher told showed me a way to derive an equation which shows the duality of matter.

We know, $E=hc/\lambda$. and $E=mc^2$

So, $hc/\lambda=mc^2$

We get, $p$ ( momentum ) = $h/\lambda$.

How were we able to equate this equation with $E=mc^2$ , as this equation is valid only for objects at rest, while we have another equation for objects that are moving i.e,

$E^2=(pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2.$

Why didn’t we equate $hc/\lambda$ with this one?

Comment: Hint: Distinguish between formulas for zero and non-zero mass.

Comment: @Qmechanic , can you please do that for me, as i donnot really know about them!

Comment: Just set m=0 in the final equation.